# Loop to find hashed data SQL

Tags: php, sql

Happy Friday! I have a database where hashed strings are uploaded with "PASSWORD_DEFAULT". In another document, the user will then be able to print a key, which will be compared with the hashes. The problem is that I do not understand how to run some code if no string was found. I may be completely wrong with the code, please help.

```
<?php
require_once('dbh.php');
$sql = 'SELECT * from license';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $hash = password_verify($_POST['key'], $row['user_key']);
    if ($hash != 0) {
        echo "Found!";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ($hash) {` - `password_verify()` returns `true` or `false`. In fact, you could actually just do `if(password_verify($_POST['key'], $row['user_key'])) {`

Comment: Why not let the database do the searching for you? If it returns no results the key is not there.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Because the values are hashed, you can't really search for them. Unless I am misunderstanding what you are saying

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Of course you can. Query the database with the hash value.

Comment: @Jacobm001 So the user should type in the hash? If you hash the word "potato", you get some hash string value back and that is what is stored in the database. If you hash the word "potato" again later, and try to search the databse with the hashed string, you will not get any results.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Melvin is generating a hash here, which is presumably what's stored in the database... Why not just generate the hash, and then search the database for the hash?

Comment: @Jacobm001 Because if the hash is generated with `password_hash`, as we're assuming here, it also contains a random salt, and without knowing that random salt you will practically never regenerate the same hash again. Catch 22.

Comment: FYI, this is a nonsensical approach. `password_hash`/`_verify` is purposefully *expensive*. If you need to call it more than a handful of times, your script is going to slow to a crawl. If your `license` table contains more than a few dozen entries, as your successful service hopefully will, the only thing you'll get from this is timeout errors.

Comment: how was the hash stored? that a key factor and do all POST arrays contain value? quite a few things can go South you know. @Melvin

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand what you mean @Fred-ii-. Values are added to the database in a separate document and are hashed with "password_hash($key, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)". Then, in another document with the code that is published in my question, I want to check if the POST data (which is posted by an input field in a form), matches with any of the hashes.

Comment: Very thankful for your information, deceze. What options are there for the current solution, assuming the database will be big? @deceze

Comment: Basically: none. Don't use `password_*` for this kind of usage. You must `SELECT` the row via some other criterion (usually the username) and then merely *verify* the hashed value.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your explanations however, really appreciate it! @deceze